# Scrapy doesn't enter in parse()

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

```
import scrapy

class IdealistaspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'idealistaspider'
    allowed_domains = ['idealista.pt']

    start_urls = ['https://www.idealista.pt/en/comprar-casas/lisboa/com-publicado_ultimas-24-horas//',
                  ]

    def parse(self, response):
        print ("Entered in parser..............................")
        next_page = response.css('a.icon-arrow-right-after::attr(href)').get()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

**Failing to enter in parse function. error logs are below**

```
2020-05-09 16:39:27 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-05-09 16:39:27 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-05-09 16:39:27 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (403) <GET https://www.idealista.pt/en/comprar-casas/lisboa/com-publicado_ultimas-24-horas//> (referer: None)
2020-05-09 16:39:27 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <403 https://www.idealista.pt/en/comprar-casas/lisboa/com-publicado_ultimas-24-horas//>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2020-05-09 16:39:27 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

**I have already set the USER-AGENT like many other solutions on internet say**

USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'

**Even tried to create a separate script (run.py) content below but issue continues**

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from spiders import idealistaspider


### Idealista
process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
    'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': False,
    'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1,
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36',
})
process.crawl(idealistaspider.IdealistaspiderSpider)
process.start()
```

Answer (score 2):

Scrapy considers non-200 responses as an error, and thus will not call your `callback` but **will** call any specified [`errback`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/2.1/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-errbacks)

Or, you can specify on a per-spider basis that you consider 403 to be an "acceptable" http response code by adding the [`handle_httpstatus_list`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/2.1/topics/spider-middleware.html#module-scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror) as a Spider attribute, a Request meta key, or even globally in `settings.py`:

```python
class MySpider(Spider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [403]
    # and all the rest
```

Comment: thanks,  adding that line sends the control to parser() but then it returns a page which is not the desired one. I mean this returned response doesn't have same html and css to extract the information.
what should I be doing to get correct response?